# Can I simply replace the first and second derivatives with the gradient and laplacian in the curvature of the graph of a function?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, curvature, laplacian

Can I simply replace the first and second derivatives with the gradient and laplacian in the curvature of the graph of a function to generalize to a multivariable curvature functional of the graph of a function?

The curvature of the graph of a function is given by the following.

$$\mathscr{k}_f(x) = \frac{f^{\prime\prime}(x)}{(1 + [f^{\prime}(x)]^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}$$

Assuming a second-differentiable scalar function, is the following a valid generalization of this type of curvature to the multivariable case?

$$\mathscr{k}_f(\vec{x}) = \frac{\nabla_{\vec{x}}^2 f(\vec{x})}{(1 + [\nabla_{\vec{x}} f(\vec{x})]^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}$$

**Edit**

[Matthew Pilling](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/801306/matthew-pilling) convinced me that taking the square of a gradient is not directly possible. I was implicitly assuming I could collapse the vectors by summing the components, however it would be technically correct to make this explicit using either dot products or the trace of the diagonal of the resulting vectors.

$$\mathscr{k}_f(\vec{x}) = \frac{\nabla_{\vec{x}}^2 f(\vec{x}) \cdot \vec{1}}{(1 + [\nabla_{\vec{x}} f(\vec{x})\cdot \vec{1}]^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}} =  \frac{\text{tr}[\text{diag}[\nabla_{\vec{x}}^2 f(\vec{x})]]}{(1 + [\text{tr}[\text{diag}[\nabla_{\vec{x}} f(\vec{x})]]]^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}$$

This is with the diagonal of a vector $\text{Diag}(\vec{x})$ being the construction of a diagonal matrix whose diagonal entries are the corresponding components of the vector $\vec{x}$.

Beyond this correction on vector operations, I'm still interested in whether the corrected equation captures the same idea of curvature as the original equation.

Comment: The expression $[\nabla_{\vec{x}} f(\vec{x})]^2$ isn't defined.

Comment: Functions can have gradients. Gradients of functions can have a square. What am I missing?

Comment: If $f(x,y)=xy$ then $\nabla f(x,y) =\big<y,x\big>$. How would you square $\nabla f(x,y)$?

Comment: Why would the gradient be an inner product? Wouldn't it just be the sum of the partial derivatives of $f$?

Comment: I used $\big< \cdot \big>$ to denote a vector, not an inner product. Also $f_x +f_y$ is the divergence of $f$, not the gradient of $f$. Lastly, the gradient is a vector, and you can't square vectors.

Comment: Okay, thank you for clarifying notation. And are $x$ and $y$ meant to be vectors or scalars?

Comment: Vectors are linear combinations, which can be squared to make higher degree polynomials.

Comment: $(x,y)$ belongs to the domain of $\nabla f:\mathbb{R}^2 \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119569/discussion-between-galen-and-matthew-pilling).

Comment: From chat: *What is the diagonal of a vector?* I think I was assuming the behaviour of [`np.diag`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.diag.html), which would give the diagonal matrix whose diagonal entries are the corresponding vector components.

Comment: From chat: *Squaring a vector is not defined.* That is true, especially without specifying the operation. I have seen $\vec{x}^2 = \vec{x} \cdot \vec{x}$, but it was clear from context. Same with  $\vec{x}^2 = \vec{x} \circ \vec{x}$ when it was clear from context that the Hadamard product was being used, although I think  $\vec{x}^{\circ 2}$ would be clearer.

Comment: You should indicate what you mean by $[\nabla_{\vec{x}}f(\vec{x})]^2$ in your original post.

Comment: @MatthewPilling I think my edit covers that, but I will add what $\text{Diag}\left( \vec{x} \right)$ is defined to be.